# mapping WCF getURL to string always returns NULL (Taleo SOAP)

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, soap-client

**QUICK SUMMARY**:
Taleo has a single operation "Dispatcher WSDL" that is supposed to return a URL for use with its WebAPI WSDL ... the purpose is to allow the URL to be for all intents and purposes soft coded.

For operation getURL,
WcfTestClient.exe XML view shows that in the SOAP envelope a URL has been returned.

However, WcfTestClient.exe formatted view shows
   Name:  (return)    Value:  (**null**)     Type:  **NullObject**

My c# vs2010 .NET 4 code; **taleoURL**  is always null

```
DispatcherAPIClient dispatcherClient = new DispatcherAPIClient("rpcrouter");
string taleoOrgCode = "TALEOSK";
string taleoURL = dispatcherClient.getURL(taleoOrgCode);
if (taleoURL == null) Console.WriteLine("null returned for " + taleoOrgCode);
```

This null is strange because here is the XML response from WcfTestClient.exe:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:getURLResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:TBEDispatcherAPI" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<return xsi:type="xsd:string">https://tbe.taleo.net/NA12/ats/services/rpcrouter</return>
</ns1:getURLResponse>

</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

https://tbe.taleo.net/NA12/ats/services/rpcrouter is the **value**
of the <**return**> element.

To be able to use the above link, obviously I need taleoURL to be not null.

Pages 154-155 of the Taleo API guide say that
getURL's defined as      string getURL(string orgCode)
 http://tbe.taleo.net/products/TBE_API_Guide.pdf   from
http://www.taleo.com/solutions/taleo-business-edition-web-integration-api

also
http://tbe.taleo.net/wsdl/DispatcherAPI.wsdl
http://tbe.taleo.net/wsdl/WebAPI.wsdl

Here's the Request/Response part of DispatcherAPI.wsdl:

```
 <wsdl:message name="getURLRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="orgCode" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getURLResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getURLReturn" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
```

My best guess is that I'm missing something.
This is a case where my own ignorance is not bliss.
MSDN and Google have not helped.

Thank you ... Gerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just started working with the Taleo WebAPI and I'm having the same issue.

Update: I changed the reference from a VS2010 C# Service Reference to an "old school" Web Reference and then it worked.  I'm still working on a "real" solution, but that does work.

Comment: Hi Pat, which "old school" Web Reference? My thinking is they might be using sonething that is less than current.  Page 10 of their .pdf API guide has a broken link to a non .NET solution. I had hoped to gain some insight by studying that; I'm waiting for their person who supports this API to get back to me.  Also, I've cross posted to forums.asp.net's WCF section but have had no answers there yet. By using your workaround solution, were you able to get Microsoft's WcfTestClient.exe to work to?  Please explain what you mean by a "real" solution. thnx  /g.

Comment: If you go in to the "Advanced" settings in VS2010 when creating a Service Reference, you can use the "Add Web Reference..." button under Compatibility.  This creates .NET 2.0 Web Services code.  I could not get the wcftestclient to work right with Taleo's API.   They use Java - Apache Axis 1.3 - for their services.

Comment: thnx Pat ... I'll try this ... by a "real" solution did you mean a .NET 4 solution?

Comment: Yeah... I was hoping to use a "Service Reference", but didn't have time to mess around as I needed to get an estimate to a client today!  Oh well... the API is a little messy, but I was able to make some basic called via .net, watching the traffic with Fiddler.

Comment: thanks for a really useful solution! too bad I've found it only when I already solved it in same way myself :)

Comment: Pat's comment helped me find a workable solution.  I'll try to post a detailed answer in the future.  I found Fiddler2 extremely useful.  I also had to study the WSDL because the documentation from Taleo was not accurate.

Comment: Tempus fugit. =~ 5 years have passed & i've still not got around to having a chunk of time to post a detailed solution (too many alligators in the swamp i'm trying to drain).  Since Pat's comment did help me find a workable solution, it's fair to mark it as the answer.  Pat, sorry this took so long because this thread was out of my sight, thus also out of my mind.